# Not able to clone through git

Tags: git, github

I tried cloning repository from github but got this error:

`fatal: unable to access '<URL>': Couldn't resolve proxy 'http.proxy'`

Even though my proxy settings are correct.

(Here `'<URL>'` is the url of repository i tried to clone)

Comment: What is the output of `git config http.proxy` ? It is your company's proxy? Github don't like such proxies :)